# show(), hide(), vanila Javascript

Tags: javascript

как без jquery сделать `show()` и `hide()` у данного примера

```js
   var obj = document.getElementById('add_show');
document.querySelector('#close_add').onclick = function() {
  obj.style.display = 'none';
};
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function() {
  obj.style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#add_show {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
#close_add {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #868686;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="add">Добавить
  <div id="add_show">
    <div id="close_add">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что должно происходить?

Comment: при клике на добавить окно появилось, при клике на крестик в окне - исчезнуть

Comment: show-hide это по сути добавление-удаление стиля display:none и все

Comment: я так и написал код, а оно не работает

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на какие элементы Вы вешаете события. Когда делаете copy/paste будьте внимательнее.

Comment: В консоли разработчика Chrome Dev Tools есть замечательный инструмент. Жмешь ctrl+shift+c или клавишу слева сверху консольки, выделяешь элемент и смотришь какие на нем стили реально висят, и какие обработчики событий.

Comment: вы правы, есть ошибка поправил, но теперь оно открывает, а закрывать не хочет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 var obj = document.getElementById('add_show');
document.querySelector('#close_add').onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  obj.style.display = 'none';
};
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function() {
  obj.style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#add_show {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
#close_add {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #868686;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="add">Добавить
  <div id="add_show">
    <div id="close_add">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**2 Ошибки**:

1. Не на том элементе показываете.

**Было**

```
document.querySelector('#close_add').onclick = function() {
  obj.style.display = 'block';
};
```

**стало**

```
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function() {
  obj.style.display = 'block';
};
```

2. Не правильная вложенность

**Было**

```
<div class="button" id="add">Добавить
    <div id="add_show">
        <div id="close_add">+</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**стало**

```
<div class="button" id="add">
  Добавить
</div>
<div id="add_show">
  <div id="close_add">+</div>
</div>
```

Так как при вашей вложенности по клику на крест сработают оба действия.